# CodeMirror's onLoad function not working?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Just curious if anyone has setup CodeMirror before and got the onLoad function to work.  With the latest version, it's not functioning.  Here's my code:

```
cydonia.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea('query', {
    height: $('#query-text-space').css('height'),
    parserfile: ["tokenizexquery.js", "parsexquery.js" ],
    stylesheet: ["/common/codemirror/css/xmlcolors.css", "/common/codemirror/css/xqcolors.css"],
    path: "/common/codemirror/js/",
    continuousScanning: false, //500,
    lineNumbers: true,
    onLoad: function (n) {
        alert('loaded');

    }
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well I figured out that for some retarded reason you can't pass it a function like that.  So I just set a variable like so:

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just specify function name, see the code below

```
cydonia.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea('query', {
    height: $('#query-text-space').css('height'),
    parserfile: ["tokenizexquery.js", "parsexquery.js" ],
    stylesheet: ["/common/codemirror/css/xmlcolors.css", "/common/codemirror/css/xqcolors.css"],
    path: "/common/codemirror/js/",
    continuousScanning: false, //500,
    lineNumbers: true,
    onLoad: codeMirrorLoaded()
}); 

function codeMirrorLoaded(){
    alert("loaded");
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what I wrote.  =)

Comment: As of the latest patch, 0.92, you can now pass it a function, as in both of these examples.

Comment: codeMirrorLoaded() immediately executes function and doesn't wait for onLoad event.

Comment: @SoftwareEnthusiastic is right, it is really wrong answer. Sure you will see alert, because you execute function instead of passing it as callback. If you need to pass it as callback you should write something like `onLoad: codeMirrorLoaded`, but not `onLoad: codeMirrorLoaded()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code I didn't find any onload function:

```
   setDefaults(CodeMirrorConfig, {
    stylesheet: [],
    path: "",
    parserfile: [],
    basefiles: ["util.js", "stringstream.js", "select.js", "undo.js", "editor.js", "tokenize.js"],
    iframeClass: null,
    passDelay: 200,
    passTime: 50,
    lineNumberDelay: 200,
    lineNumberTime: 50,
    continuousScanning: false,
    saveFunction: null,
    onChange: null,
    undoDepth: 50,
    undoDelay: 800,
    disableSpellcheck: true,
    textWrapping: true,
    readOnly: false,
    width: "",
    height: "300px",
    minHeight: 100,
    autoMatchParens: false,
    parserConfig: null,
    tabMode: "indent", // or "spaces", "default", "shift"
    enterMode: "indent", // or "keep", "flat"
    electricChars: true,
    reindentOnLoad: false,
    activeTokens: null,
    cursorActivity: null,
    lineNumbers: false,
    firstLineNumber: 1,
    indentUnit: 2,
    domain: null,
    noScriptCaching: false
  });
```

I know it is in the manual, but not in the code (codemirror.js).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, CodeMirror "loads synchronously, so as soon as the constructor returns, you can use it." https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codemirror/oXEdDS5ef64

I couldn't get anything running using the fromTextArea method, but the following approach worked for me:

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, el);
    // onLoad script here
}, {
    value: el.value
});
```

[UPDATE]

I've managed to get it to work using fromTextArea(). Initially the content wasn't appearing but using myCodeMirror.refresh(); fixed this problem.

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(el);
// onLoad script here
myCodeMirror.refresh();
```